# javax.jcr.RepositoryException trying to follow Adobe example

Tags: java, aem, jcr, jackrabbit

I'm trying to follow this example from Adobe:

[How to programmatically access the AEM JCR](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-65/developing/platform/access-jcr.html?lang=en)

My code looks like this:

```
    package com.example;
    
    import javax.jcr.Repository;
    import javax.jcr.Session;
    import javax.jcr.SimpleCredentials;
    import javax.jcr.Node;
    
    import org.apache.jackrabbit.commons.JcrUtils;
    
    /**
     * Hello world!
     *
     */
    public class App 
    {
        public static void main( String[] args )
        {        
            try {
                //Create a connection to the CQ repository running on local host
                Repository repository = JcrUtils.getRepository("http://localhost:4502/crx/server");                     
    
            } catch (Exception ex){
                System.out.println(ex.toString());
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

My pom.xml has these dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jackrabbit</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackrabbit-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.21.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jackrabbit</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackrabbit-jcr-commons</artifactId>
        <version>2.21.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jackrabbit</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackrabbit-jcr2dav</artifactId>
        <version>2.21.7</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

When I run with this command:

```
`java -jar .\target\demo-jar-with-dependencies.jar`
```

I get the following output:

```
    javax.jcr.RepositoryException: Unable to access a repository with the following settings:
        org.apache.jackrabbit.repository.uri: http://localhost:4502/crx/server
    The following RepositoryFactory classes were consulted:
        org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryFactoryImpl: declined
    Perhaps the repository you are trying to access is not available at the moment.
    javax.jcr.RepositoryException: Unable to access a repository with the following settings:
        org.apache.jackrabbit.repository.uri: http://localhost:4502/crx/server
    The following RepositoryFactory classes were consulted:
        org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryFactoryImpl: declined
    Perhaps the repository you are trying to access is not available at the moment.
            at org.apache.jackrabbit.commons.JcrUtils.getRepository(JcrUtils.java:224)
            at org.apache.jackrabbit.commons.JcrUtils.getRepository(JcrUtils.java:264)
            at com.example.App.main(App.java:20)
```

I've found a number of articles both here and on other sites but none of the suggestions I've found have done anything to resolve the issue.

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?  I'm pretty new to AEM.  Yes, the AEM Author server is running and it's on port 4502.  In fact if I open this URL in a web browser I get:

[image: http://localhost:4502/crx/server]

Which seems normal.

---

**Update**: The consensus seems to be that I'm going about this incorrectly by using Maven and not downloading the Jackrabbit Standalone library from Apache.  So I created an entirely new project in Eclipse, without Maven, and added jackrabbit-standalone.jar Version 2.23.0 (which is the latest) as a reference library.  The result is exactly the same:

[image: trying with Jackrabbit Standalone]

I've setup a Github repository for this code at:

[Github Repo](https://github.com/jwhance/AEM_Access)

Please feel free to clone it and see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: It might help to run this with DEBUG logging. You could also check with curl whether the URI you have responds correctly to HTTP PROPFIND requests.

Comment: Did you think about some authentication? The current session is unauthenticated and I am not sure you can access WebDAV without a session.

Answer (score 0):

We usually write our AEM code in OSGi bundles that we deploy in AEM. If you want to use the JCR API to connect to an AEM instance follow the advice [here](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-65/developing/platform/access-jcr.html?lang=en):

> To use the JCR API, add the jackrabbit-standalone-2.4.0.jar file to
> your Java application’s classpath. You can obtain this JAR file from
> the Java JCR API web page at
> https://jackrabbit.apache.org/jcr/jcr-api.html.

Once you download that file you have two options:

1/ No Maven - compile your program manually using `javac -classpath ...` (and specify the jackrabbit-standalone JAR in the classpath), and run it using `java -cp ...`

2/ With Maven - install the JAR in the Maven repo (or add it as a dependency using `<scope>system<scope>`, but you also have to run your program using Maven

Note that the Maven dependencies do not affect the program, the jackrabbit-standalone JAR is all you need to run the code you wrote.

Comment: I need to run this outside the context of AEM.  In other words, it's a standalone application that needs to access some of the data in the JCR repository in AEM.  From what I have read this is possible, but I not getting it to work so far.

Comment: The link you posted is the same link that I posted in the question. I don't have jackrabbit-standalone in my deps so I'll add that and see if it helps.

Comment: Yes, it's the same link, I just pointed you to the advice ;).

Comment: I built the example myself and didn't use other dependencies than `jackrabbit-standalone`

Comment: I'm not sure there is a jackrabbit-standalone 2.4.0.  I see only 1.6.5: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jackrabbit/jackrabbit-standalone/1.6.5

Comment: But I am trying that one now.

Comment: It's not in Maven central, you have to download it from the website. You can add the JAR as a dependency afterwards.

Comment: Please use a *current* version of jackrabbit-standalone. See http://jackrabbit.apache.org/jcr/downloads.html

Answer (score 0):

So you're trying to access AEM using Jackrabbit WebDV.

It's pretty clear that you don't have the right components in the class path. You likely need all "spi" related components (these can the WebDAV-related client code), plus "jackrabbit-jcr-commons".

You definitively do *not* need core; as that would a for a local repository instance.

Comment: It may be clear to you but obviously it's not clear to me.  Please supply some justification for this answer.  A short example would be most appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "all 'spi' related components" here?

Comment: All components that contain the string "spi" in their name.